# How to set response headers in .NET core 2.0 service

Tags: c#, http-headers, .net-core

I have a dotnet core 2 service and I would like to add a response header before sending the response, but I cannot figure out how to do so. The header's value will depend on the request, it will not be the same for all requests. Sample endpoint where I would like to add this is below.

```
[HttpPost("MyEndpoint")]
public string MyEndpoint([FromBody][Required] RequestBody requestBody)
{
    string responseBody = DoStuff(requestBody);

    // How to set response header?

    return responseBody;
}
```

p.s. sorry for the stupid username, i was in a rush to create the account but now I can't change it for 30 (25 more) days.

Comment: You need to return `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: +1 to SLaks comment. Here's some example code on how to return a HttpResponseMessage with modified headers: [HttpResponseMessage](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/paging-in-aspnet-webapi-http-headers/)

Comment: Similar to the issue I had with the reply from Fouad, the `Request` object also does not appear to exist in this scope. I did find a solution and added it below. If you know what's missing to make the `Request` and `Response` objects accessible I would be curious to know. The example linked does not explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to get the previous reply's solution to work because `this.Response` does not seem to exist, but I did find a solution that works.

First, in `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)` add the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Next, add an HttpContext member to the service controller and inject `HttpContextAccessor` to the service controller constructor as follows:

```
private readonly HttpContext Context;

public MyServiceController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ...)
{
    Context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
}
```

Last, use the new `Context` member to modify the header. Modified version of the method in the original post:

```
[HttpPost("MyEndpoint")]
public string MyEndpoint([FromBody][Required] RequestBody requestBody)
{
    string responseBody = DoStuff(requestBody);

    // Set response header
    Context.Response.Header.Add("HeaderKey", "HeaderValue");

    return responseBody;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost("MyEndpoint")]
public string MyEndpoint([FromBody][Required] RequestBody requestBody)
{
    string responseBody = DoStuff(requestBody);

    // How to set response header?
    this.Response.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "MyHeaderValue");

    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `this.Response` does not exist. I did find a working solution which I will add below.

Answer (score 0):

in .net core this is very simple to do:

```
Response.Headers.Add("testkey", "testvalue");
```